# Laravel namespace in relations confused me

Tags: php, laravel-4, namespaces, relationship, laravel-facade

In my app I have Event and User models.Because of Event model I have to put it into namespace .so I created namespace as of following.

**Event**

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

class Event extends \Eloquent {
   public function user()
   {
     return $this->belongsTo('User');
   }
```

**User**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;
use App\Models\Event;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {
   public function events()
   {
     return $this->hasMany('Event');
   }
```

The relations between User and Event are simple OneToMany. So in my **EventController** I use POST method to create new event resource .

```
$e = new Event(array('keys'=>'values')); //without user_id filled
$user->events()->save($e);
```

At the same time i got an error .

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event::newQuery()
```

If I am not wrong i guess it is namespace error.But namespaces are already declared correctly I guess.
But I try visiting similar questions and used alternative way in relationship and then it worked fine.Personally I don't find it satisfied.Any idea why this is occurred ? 
Change the above relation to

```
public function events()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('\App\Models\Event');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put `Event` inside a namespace you need to use it with it's fully qualified classname.

You can either import it into your controller:

```
use App\Models\Event;
```

Or specify the namespace inline:

```
new App\Models\Event();
```

Also, I would recommend that if you create a namespace for models that you put all of them in there. (`User` is missing a `namespace` in your code)

Comment: Hi @lukasgeiter, I've already put **use App\Models\Event;** in controllers in which i am going to use .

Comment: And if you specify the namespace when you use it? (my second code block)